# How to make just one module in Linux kernel?

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, linux-device-driver

I modified a driver in Linux kernel.
Then, how can I make it?
I used 'make modules',but the kernel made a lot of modules.
So can I make just one module in the kernel?
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Run 'make modules' again. It should only recompile source code you have edited.

Answer (score 0):

```
make -C ../../../themis.kernel/ M=`pwd` nf_conntrack.ko
```

this command will only make nf_conntrack.ko.
you can use this command to make your module